# AS3 Class Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript

I am trying to make a game in flash using AS3. I am making a class file that set the parameters for creating a new planet, but when I then add the actions to the first frame of the timeline, it immediately gives me an error. I am new to action script and would love any help. My code should work as far as I know. Here it is:

The actions menu contains this code on the first frame -

```
var zuun:MovieClip = new Planet();
```

The class "Planet" looks like this, and is saved in a file name "Planet.as" and is targeted at my main file.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Planet extends MovieClip {

        private var planetname:String;

        public function Planet() {
            // constructor code
        }

        public function setName(a:String):void {
            planetname = a;
        }

        public function getName():String {
            return planetname;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

The error i'm getting is this  -

```
Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///Users/mike/Desktop/jonah/bindings.swf contains     invalid data.
at Planet/frame1()[Planet::frame1:1]
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please paste the error message you get?

Comment: I edited the question with the error

Comment: I copied your exact code and created a Flash project and it worked without error.  I would double check that the code on frame 1 is correct. My test was done in Flash CC 2014.